# Display button when cursor over on <a> tag

Tags: html, css

How to display button when cursor over on `<a>` tag ?

I did this with CSS, I've tried the following but did not work:

CSS Part:

```css
.NameClass:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML Part:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="current-path-button NameClass" >
   Shop
    <ul class="dropdown-menu customize-dropdown-menu" style="display: none">
        <li><i style="color: black; font-size: 36px;" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is right, just, put `display:none` into your external css, your problem is caused by inline css overriding that css!

[check this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyifw)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
a:hover + button {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Xg22U/

For your code, you can use this:

```
.NameClass:hover + ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: it is better if you provide some explain about your code, and take some look at the question code.

Comment: What's the problem? The code isn't minimized or something? :) But you agreed the code is working, so?

Comment: `+` this selector select that element is in same parent and after it. but the problem is with the `<ul>` that is **in** the `<a>`. so your code do not work in this case

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.NameClass:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
   }
```

it is because of prioritize. inline styling is in high priority than CSS style, so you need set `!important` after CSS style.

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gJkJT/3/)

Comment: please comment down voter... what is the problem with this code ?